# Docker compose mongo: Overriding entrypoint

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to setup a MongoDB with replicaset with Docker Compose:

```
services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: mongo-rs-primary
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    volumes:
      - ./_docker/volumes/mongo1:/data/db
      - ./_docker/mongo-rs-key:/data/mongo-rs-key
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod 400 /data/mongo-rs-key
        chown 999:999 /data/mongo-rs-key
        exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$0
    command: --replSet rs0 --keyFile /data/mongo-rs-key --port 27017

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: mongo-rs-replica1
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    volumes:
      - ./_docker/volumes/mongo2:/data/db
      - ./_docker/mongo-rs-key:/data/mongo-rs-key
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod 400 /data/mongo-rs-key
        chown 999:999 /data/mongo-rs-key
        exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$0
    command: --replSet rs0 --keyFile /data/mongo-rs-key --port 27018

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: mongo-rs-replica2
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    volumes:
      - ./_docker/volumes/mongo3:/data/db
      - ./_docker/mongo-rs-key:/data/mongo-rs-key
    ports:
      - 27019:27019
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        chmod 400 /data/mongo-rs-key
        chown 999:999 /data/mongo-rs-key
        exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$0
    command: --replSet rs0 --keyFile /data/mongo-rs-key --port 27019
```

Note that I needed to override the ownership of the security key file and I found online this is one way to do it, however, the weird thing is now my replica set name is `--auth` and not `rs0`? I suspect its because of `exec docker-entrypoint.sh $$0` but whats wrong? I copied that from somewhere, seems like its using `--auth` in `--replSet` instead of `rs0`

Comment: I might expect the permission changes you're trying to make to also affect the ownership of the file on the host system.  Can you run the `chmod` and `chown` commands on your host, and remove these `entrypoint:` overrides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're only passing the first `--replSet` option to the image's entrypoint script.  I might change the place you pass on the option from `$0` to `"$@"`, making sure to pass all the options and to correctly quote it, and then insert an extra argument to be the (now unused) `$0` value.

```yaml
entrypoint:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - |
    ...
    exec docker-entrypoint.sh "$$@"
  - entrypoint-script
command: --replSet rs0 ...
```

The [syntax of `sh -c`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117) is

```bash
sh -c command_string command_name argument ...
```

where `command_name` becomes the `$0` value inside `command_string`, and the `argument`s become `$1`, `$2`, and so on.  So adding an explicit value for the `command_name` argument should help resolve the syntax.

In your original formation, this gets put together as:

1. Compose parses the YAML;
2. Compose [replaces](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) `$$` with `$` inside the string;
3. The string-format `command:` is split into words;
4. The overridden `entrypoint:` and `command:` are concatenated together.

This gives you a command like

```bash
sh -c "...\nexec docker-entrypoint.sh \$0\n" --replSet rs0 ...
```

Notice in this command we're only inserting the single parameter `$0`, and the option in that position is `--replSet`.  The remaining options just get ignored.

I suspect the original pattern you had found would work if you could force Compose to make the `command:` into a single string, maybe by embedding it into a YAML list `command: [--replSet rs0 ...]`.  Then the unquoted parameter expansion `$0` would do word splitting after evaluating the parameter value.  It's usually not a good practice in shell scripts to rely on this, though.